# Calling stored procedure from Hibernate / MySQL: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures

I receive the following error when calling insert stored procedure in Hibernate while working with MySQL db:

```
Hibernate: 
    { call InsertPayment(?, ?) }
sie 28, 2013 10:17:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
sie 28, 2013 10:17:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [model_mapping_xml.TPayment]
```

Stored procedure definition in MySQL db:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertPayment(
                    IN pIdAnother INT,  
                    IN pAmount DECIMAL(19,4)                                
                    )
BEGIN 
...       
END
```

TPayment.hbm.xml file contains:

```
<sql-insert callable="true" check="none">
    { call InsertPayment(?, ?) }
</sql-insert>
```

Implicit call of the stored procedure:

```
// calling the stored procedure to add payment
TPayment newp = new TPayment();
newp.setAnother((TAnother) session.load(TAnother.class, 1));
newp.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(20));
session.save(newp);
```

Why does it say "3 > number of parameters" where everywhere there are 2 parameters for this procedure?
(I can call deletePayment and modifyPayment stored procedures in similar way and they work fine...).

TPayment mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model_mapping_xml.TPayment" table="TPayment" catalog="DB">
        <id name="idPayment" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="IdPayment" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <version name="rowvers" type="timestamp" generated="always">
            <column name="Rowvers" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </version>
        <many-to-one name="another" class="model_mapping_xml.TAnother" fetch="select">
            <column name="IdAnother" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="amount" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="Amount" scale="4" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="date1" type="timestamp">
            <column name="Date1" length="19" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <sql-insert callable="true" check="none">
            { call InsertPayment(?, ?) }
        </sql-insert>
        <sql-update callable="true" check="none">
            { call ModifyPayment(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }
        </sql-update>
        <sql-delete callable="true" check="none">
            { call DeletePayment(?, ?) }
        </sql-delete>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

TAnother mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model_mapping_xml.TAnother" table="TAnother" catalog="DB">
        <id name="idAnother" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="IdAnother" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="dateBegin" type="date">
            <column name="DateBegin" length="10" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateEnd" type="date">
            <column name="DateEnd" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="rowvers" type="timestamp">
            <column name="Rowvers" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="payment" table="TPayment" 
                inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="IdAnother" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="model_mapping_xml.TPayment" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: post TPayment/TAnother definition, sometimes is a problem related to same columns mapped multiple times

Comment: updated definitions (it's xml mapping so I guess it's enough)

Comment: Probably you are missing a `?` related to `TPayment.date1` column

Comment: Hmm, but I don't have this column in the stored procedure header (because I don't want to have it there, date1 is generated inside the stored procedure so there's no need to pass it via the parameter).

Comment: documentation is not explicit, but I think you can't insert only a subset of your property or you are missing output parameter as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/querysql-cud.html)

Comment: Ok, I can live with that, I just want to be sure if that's the reason, could anybody else confirm that please?